# how to get file path on android?

Tags: android

I am noob in android, my question is how to get real path of file in android ?

I am using intent to choose file, here is the codes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String path = data.getData().getPath();
                Log.d("File Location", path);
            break;
    }
}
```

but the result is like "/external/images/media/1387"

I expect is like /sdcard/folder/file.ext

Comment: yes. this the real path. That means that your file is in a folder called 'images' in your phone external memory. What exactly do you want ?

Comment: Why do you want a real path? You shouldn't ever need a real path as you can open the file directly with [getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()))](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri))

Answer (score 5):

//kotlin

```
object URIPathHelper {

    fun getRealPath(context: Context?, fileUri: Uri?): String? {
        return getRealPathFromURIAPI19(context!!, fileUri!!)!!
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi", "ObsoleteSdkInt")
    private fun getRealPathFromURIAPI19(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]

                // This is for checking Main Memory
                return if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    if (split.size > 1) {
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
                    } else {
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"
                    }
                    // This is for checking SD Card
                } else {
                    "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/")
                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                val fileName = getFilePath(context, uri)
                if (fileName != null) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString() + "/Download/" + fileName
                }
                var id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                    id = id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
                    val file = File(id)
                    if (file.exists()) return id
                }
                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    java.lang.Long.valueOf(id)
                )
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                var contentUri: Uri? = null
                when (type) {
                    "image" -> {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    }
                    "video" -> {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    }
                    "audio" -> {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    }
                }
                val selection = "_id=?"
                val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
                    split[1]
                )
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
            }
        } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true))
            return if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) uri.lastPathSegment else getDataColumn(
                context,
                uri,
                null,
                null
            ) else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return uri.path
        }
            // Return the remote address
        return null
    }

    private fun getDataColumn(
        context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<String>?
    ): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(
            column
        )
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                uri!!, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null
            )
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(index)
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return null
    }


    private fun getFilePath(context: Context, uri: Uri?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
        )
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                uri!!, projection, null, null,
                null
            )
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                return cursor.getString(index)
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    private fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri.authority
    }
}
```

//java

```
public class GetFilePathFromDevice {
        /**
         * Get file path from URI
         *
         * @param context context of Activity
         * @param uri     uri of file
         * @return path of given URI
         */
    
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
            final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
            // DocumentProvider
            if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
                // ExternalStorageProvider
                if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];
                    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                    }
                }
                // DownloadsProvider
                else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }
                // MediaProvider
                else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];
                    Uri contentUri = null;
                    if ("image".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    }
                    final String selection = "_id=?";
                    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                }
            }
            // MediaStore (and general)
            else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                // Return the remote address
                if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                    return uri.getLastPathSegment();
                return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
            }
            // File
            else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
            return null;
        }
    
        public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            final String column = "_data";
            final String[] projection = {column};
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    return cursor.getString(index);
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
            return null;
        }
    
        public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }
    
        public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }
    
        public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }
    
        public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
            return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }
```

Comment: thanks @Imranrana07 It works well, but still I don't get it, why it's so hard just to get a file path in android development ??, I tried to browse file with different activity(apps) and some of them gave the correct result of the actual file location.

Comment: this will works to get file's path from any location SD/phone memory as well any media file. that is why. And it will work for any version no worries. broid

Comment: What an excellent answer! I've tested it on 4.4.4, 6.0, 6.0.1 and 7.0 devices and it works flawlessly. Needs more upvotes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: thank a lot !!! I have look for this all over the net

Answer (score -2):

**This is What Basically Every One Do**

```
Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
```

**Use This Method To Get RealPath**

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
String result;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
    result = contentURI.getPath();
} else { 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    result = cursor.getString(idx);
    cursor.close();
}
return result;
```

}

**Close Cursor At End For Better Purformance**