# Android getPath() from Uri not working

Tags: android, file, path

On huawei honor 8 with android 7.0 the uri.getPath() returns something like /external/file/3344 instead of real path of the file.This code also works fine on many devices and also on android emulator with android 7.0 and uri.getPath() returns /storage/emulated/0/PCalculator/main.js but not on honor 8. I used Intent to choose a file in my program as below :

```
private void fileBrowse(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser
                (intent,"Open File"),RCODE_OPENFILE);
}
```

And in onActivityResult I want to read the file as below :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    switch(requestCode){
        case RCODE_OPENFILE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK &&
                    data != null && data.getData() != null){
                fileOpen(data.getData());
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

And the fileOpen function :

```
private void fileOpen(Uri uri){

    File mFile = new File(uri.getPath());
    StringBuilder mText = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mFile));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            mText.append(line);
            mText.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    etCode.setText(mText);
    tvTitle.setText(mFile.getName());
}
```

Comment: you cannot get "real path of the file", use `InputStream` instead, read `ContentResolver` API docs on how to get one

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109946/how-to-get-file-path-on-android